# php mvc - apply model's methods to result from db

Tags: php, oop, model

In many php frameworks we can do something like:

```
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $first;
    protected $second;

    public function getAllAttributes() {
        return $this->first.','.$this->second;
    }
}
```

How to do this in my own solution? My current model:

```
class Model
{

    // ..

    public function all() {
        return mysqli_query($con, 'select * from '.$this->table);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
$test = new Test();
$result = $test->all();
foreach ($result as $t) {
    echo $t->getAllAttributes();
}
```

Comment: But I think they might be storing values within their variables from constructor or somewhere else it doesn't came magically within those variables

Comment: I think you want to (or can) use PDO's [`setFetchMode`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) for selecting results directly into a predefined class (`PDO::FETCH_CLASS`)

Comment: wow, it looks great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to create objects of the current class from a MySQL query, without handling query generation and object instantiation in each model again.

The pattern that you describe, where the model is responsible to load itself, is called *Active Record* and was made popular by Ruby on Rails, then adapted in PHP frameworks like CakePHP and Laravel.

There is no single solution how to implement it, look at the code of these frameworks to understand how they work.

The important part is that the models must somehow describe themselves, i.e. which attributes are loaded from the database, what are their data types, which table is used. This can be based on the `DESCRIBE $table` result in MySQL, via "Annotations" and reflection, or explicitly with code.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know how is it called and what to google :)